# How can i add and remove multiple pages in horizontal viewpager for android?

Tags: android, android-layout

here i have one application in which i used viewpager. i want to add and remove views from pageadapter dynamically with programming.

now i add only 4 views static to this PagerAdapter.

```
private ArrayList<LinearLayout> views;

public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) 
{
      views = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
      views.add(new ListView1Page(context));            
      views.add(new TextViewPage(context));
      views.add(new ListView2Page(context));
      views.add(new ButtonPage(context));
}
```

please help if any body have idea. give some links which can be helpful to me

Comment: Have you tried following the [`ViewPager` example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) at Google dev? Full code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java) and shows how to use `instantiateItem()` and `destroyItem` to respectively add and remove views from the ViewPager.

Comment: @MH i seen this example but its remove from container after calling destroyitem but i want to remove actually from the application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "remove actually from the application". There are some more extensive examples of using a ViewPager in the install directory of Compatibility Package rev. 3 you might want to take a look at.

Comment: @MH. see dude. i want to delete permanent that page(screen) from that adapter after performing particular event

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a fragment adapter, my solution might work for you.  Please see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager).