# How to add new page to viewPager dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I use custom pager adapter to represent each page as a fragment as in the following code:

```
private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        return pages.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MAX_NUMBER_PAGES;
    }       
}
```

The above PageAdapter class requires me to know the number of pages of the viewPager in advance. However I don't know how many pages I would have in the ViewPager. So, Is it possible to return 1 in getCount() method and then add the new page in the button click event or in the onPageChangeListener()?

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing to what you are asking, except I used FrameLayout instead of a Fragment.  You might be able to adapt from my code:
[dynamicall add and remove view to viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check your solution and let you know.