# Customize ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to create a `ViewPager` where on first screen of `ViewPager` I have an image, second screen shows gallery, third screen shows image,texts and buttons.

The app I am writing is for version 2.3.3

I am stuck and confused on how to begin this implementation.

Comment: You can use a ViewPager with a fragment adapter with a fragment for your image, a fragment for your gallery, and a fragment for your image/text/buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide pager adapter.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager) a good example of it

After creation adapter all what you need is just add views to adapter

```
pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.view_pager);
pager.setAdapter (pagerAdapter);

// Create an initial view to display; must be a subclass of FrameLayout.
FrameLayout v0 = (FrameLayout) View.inflate(R.layout.one_of_my_page_layouts, null);
pagerAdapter.addView (v0, 0);
```