# How to make the view visible and invisible in viewpager in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am having problem in making the view visible and invisible in viewpager.My requirement is i want to make the view invisible on click of a button or a image,but this action is happening on the next consecutive page.
Here is the adapter class which i have tried

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, int noofsize) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    size = noofsize;
    act = mainActivity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return size;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpages, null);
    click = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.click);
    text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

And Activity class is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int noofsize = 4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            noofsize);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.reviewpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

Comment: Set listener only for the page you need to make invisible by checking your position. if(poition==0){ //set click listener}.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager. It may help

Comment: @Nandhiya Is this your requirement? http://pastie.org/8186251

Comment: yes this is the requirement.