# Removing/Adding a Page to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm trying to make a layout that is essentially a fragment consisting of 3 vertically scrolling lists. Clicking an item in the list will populate the list to its immediate right with appropriate data, and so on. When an item in the right-most list is clicked, a new fragment will be introduced. So what I am trying to achieve is a way to add the 2nd fragment when the final item is clicked, and have functionality such that a swipe to the right will bring you back to the first fragment and remove the second one. It seems that using a ViewPager with a custom FragmentPagerAdapter is the way to go, but I am not quit sure how to implement the adapter to accommodate my specific functionality.

I was also looking at the accepted answer on this post: [dynamically add and remove view to viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager).
It seems to be close to what I want, but I am not quite sure and I'm also unsure as to how to adapt this to a FragmentPagerAdapter, specifically how I would implement getItem().

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I believe I've found an adequate solution to my problem.

I created my FragmentPagerAdapter so that the first page is initialized normally, but the second page is merely a container that will initialize the fragment later.

```
public static class ContractDetailsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int numFrags = 2;

    public ContractDetailsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String argObject = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new SectionsFragment();
            argObject = SectionsFragment.ARG_OBJECT;
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new DetailsFragmentContainer();
            argObject = DetailsFragmentContainer.ARG_OBJECT;
            break;
        default:
            Log.e("ContractDetailsPagerAdapter", "called getItem outofbounds");
            return null;
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(argObject, position+1);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numFrags;
    }
}
```

In the FragmentPagerAdapter, SectionsFragment is a first fragment that has the 3 ListViews, and the DetailsFragmentContainer is merely a container that will initialize DetailsFragment later on.

```
public class DetailsFragmentContainer extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "details_fragment_container";

Bundle ids;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ids = getArguments();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_container, container, false);
    return v;
}

public void createDetailsFragment(int parentItemId) {
    Fragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
    ids.putInt(Columns.COLUMN_PARENTITEMID, parentItemId);
    fragment.setArguments(ids);
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragments_frame, fragment).commit();
}

}
```

and the XML layout for the container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragments_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

The parentitemid is what I needed to get later on when an item in the 3rd column is clicked from the SectionsFragment.

Then, using the accepted answer from [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s/9650884#9650884) , I adapted it slightly so that the ability to be swiped can be set.

```
public class SetSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

boolean canSwipe = false;

public SetSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SetSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!canSwipe) {
        return false;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!canSwipe) {
        return false;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void canSwipe(boolean swipeable) {
    canSwipe = swipeable;
}
}
```

With this, we can simply set the ability to swipe to false when we are in the first page, and enable it when we leave.

First, we set a listener to check when we select the first page and disable swipe.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if (position == 0)
                        mViewPager.canSwipe(false);
                }
            });
```

When we select an item in the 3rd list, we create the DetailsFragment and put it in the DetailsFragmentContainer, set the current item to 1 so that the viewpager will show the 2nd page, and then reenable to swipe.

```
public void OnSection3Selected(long id) {
    int parentItemId = ContractDetailsActivity.getItemId(id, getActivity());

    ...

    ((DetailsFragmentContainer) fragment).createDetailsFragment(parentItemId);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    mViewPager.canSwipe(true);
}
```

I hope this is helpful to someone!