# How to dynamically add image to a viewpager containing imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in my main_layout. The view pager contains only an ImageView wrapped by RelativeLayout

What i would like to do is when a user click on a button, it will add an image to that particular viewpager.

I found this answer here on stackoverflow (which i think it is relevant to my question), however i am completely lost with that code.

[Dynamically Adding View to viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager)

So far this is my code:

MainActivity.Java

```
private PagerAdapter pAdapter;
private ViewPager photoPager;

...

pAdapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext());
photoPager.setAdapter(pAdapter);

GalleryPagerAdapter.java

public class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private final Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };

    public GalleryPagerAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = 10;
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        container.addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

This is the view that i would like to add dynamically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity where my ViewPager exists

```
MainActivity.xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/photoPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:background="#4F4E4F"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So my question is how do i improve the code i am using so that i can dynamically add new image to my ViewPager

ps: On the reference link (which i strongly believe relevant to my question), i am completely lost on this part:

```
// Create an initial view to display; must be a subclass of FrameLayout.
FrameLayout v0 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate (R.layout.one_of_my_page_layouts, null);
pagerAdapter.addView (v0, 0);
```

*What is inflater ?? What should i initialize it to?*

I hope someone could direct me. And i am sorry if i sound like asking multiple question here.

Comment: would you like to add images from SD card?

Comment: Yes, user shall be able to browse through from their phone gallery.

Comment: ok, it will some time to develop the answer for you.

Comment: I will patiently wait.. :) In the mean time i'll tinker about that reference link i came across.

Comment: You extend PageAdapter but there need one this startOnActivityResult() method

Comment: i am getting images as bitmaps. how to store them dynamically and then show them?

Answer (score 3):

Inflater is used to create View object out of your xml layout.

So if your lauout `R.layout.one_of_my_page_layouts`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inflater will do something like this(Just an example)

```
ImageView iv=new ImageView(context);
RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(context);
rl.add(iv)
return rl;
```

Just the minimal code but inflater will set all the layout params as well.

So instead of create a view dynamically like you are doing in `instantiateItem` if you have an xml you can simply inflate it and get an object of Type view.

So you can change `instantiateItem` to:

```
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        RelativeLayout v0 = (RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate (R.layout.one_of_my_page_layouts, null);

        ImageView imageView = vo.findViewById(R.id.photo_thumb);
        int padding = 10;
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        container.addView(v0, 0);
        return v0;
    }
```

Comment: Can't the ViewPager hold an ImageView directly? Using a layout for a single view seems excessive when the code could just created the ImageView and add it to the collection.