# Fragments lock after page swipe?

Tags: android

Is is possible to LOCKED fragments on button click?
For example.. Im making a quiz app but it is in Fragment form..
after clicking the SUBMIT BUTTON. you must swipe to the next page or the QUESTION 2.java.
now the thing is..
I want to disable the PREVIOUS fragment so you cannot go back to QUESTION 1.
Thank you guys!
my code..

QUESTION 1.JAVA

public class Question1 extends Fragment{

```
RadioButton q1a2;
Button btn1;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question1, null);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    q1a2 = (RadioButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.q1a2);
    btn1 = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnq1);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Submitted",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (q1a2.isChecked()){
                editor.putInt("answer_value", 1);
            } else {
                editor.putInt("answer_value", 0);
            }
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

}
```

}

QUESTION 2.JAVA

```
public class Question2 extends Fragment{

RadioButton q2a1;
Button btn2;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question2, null);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    q2a1 = (RadioButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.q2a1);
    btn2 = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.q2_button);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

            if (q2a1.isChecked()){
                editor.putInt("answer_value2", 1);
            } else {
                editor.putInt("answer_value2", 0);
            }
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using a viewpager?

Comment: yes sir Im using a view pager. xml

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the old fragments from the viewpager dynamically, as the user moves forward:

[dynamically add and remove view to viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager)