# How to create dynamic ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have been trying to create dynamically pages but they lag too much. I tried doing like here: https://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java

or here: [dynamically add and remove view to viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager)

They both basically do same thing and they both get extremely laggy with my view.

Here is what I want to do, and what I get:

[image] [image]

Also I get "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread" warning.
 Is there any way I can make this optimized? 
And for reference, how is this kind of view called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I get "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread" warning.

That would be why it is lagging.

> Is there any way I can make this optimized?

You are welcome to [enable `StrictMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html), and you are welcome to use tools like [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to determine where you are spending your time on the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Background image and the grey one were too big.