# Adding fragment and set it as first position in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm adding a fragment to a ViewPager. If I want to create and add another fragment I just call notifyDataSetChanged() method on ViewPagerAdapter custom class and change the number of returned items. It works well..

The problem is that I want every new fragment appear in the first place of ViewPager instead on the last one. For example currently is like that:

- Fragment1
  ->Adding Fragment2
- Fragment1, Fragment2
  ->Adding Fragment3
- Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3

I would like to be like this in ViewPager:

1. Fragment1
   ->Adding Fragment2
2. Fragment2, Fragment1
   ->Adding Fragment3
3. Fragment3, Fragment2, Fragment1

How can I achieve this with viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671777/3482000)

Basically you need to extend a `PagerAdapter` and expose the method to add an element at a specific position.

```
class MainPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
  // This holds all the currently displayable views, in order from left to right.
  private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Used by ViewPager.  "Object" represents the page; tell the ViewPager where the
  // page should be displayed, from left-to-right.  If the page no longer exists,
  // return POSITION_NONE.
  @Override
  public int getItemPosition (Object object)
  {
    int index = views.indexOf (object);
    if (index == -1)
      return POSITION_NONE;
    else
      return index;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Used by ViewPager.  Called when ViewPager needs a page to display; it is our job
  // to add the page to the container, which is normally the ViewPager itself.  Since
  // all our pages are persistent, we simply retrieve it from our "views" ArrayList.
  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
  {
    View v = views.get (position);
    container.addView (v);
    return v;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Used by ViewPager.  Called when ViewPager no longer needs a page to display; it
  // is our job to remove the page from the container, which is normally the
  // ViewPager itself.  Since all our pages are persistent, we do nothing to the
  // contents of our "views" ArrayList.
  @Override
  public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
  {
    container.removeView (views.get (position));
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Used by ViewPager; can be used by app as well.
  // Returns the total number of pages that the ViewPage can display.  This must
  // never be 0.
  @Override
  public int getCount ()
  {
    return views.size();
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Used by ViewPager.
  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)
  {
    return view == object;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Add "view" to right end of "views".
  // Returns the position of the new view.
  // The app should call this to add pages; not used by ViewPager.
  public int addView (View v)
  {
    return addView (v, views.size());
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Add "view" at "position" to "views".
  // Returns position of new view.
  // The app should call this to add pages; not used by ViewPager.
  public int addView (View v, int position)
  {
    views.add (position, v);
    return position;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Removes "view" from "views".
  // Retuns position of removed view.
  // The app should call this to remove pages; not used by ViewPager.
  public int removeView (ViewPager pager, View v)
  {
    return removeView (pager, views.indexOf (v));
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Removes the "view" at "position" from "views".
  // Retuns position of removed view.
  // The app should call this to remove pages; not used by ViewPager.
  public int removeView (ViewPager pager, int position)
  {
    // ViewPager doesn't have a delete method; the closest is to set the adapter
    // again.  When doing so, it deletes all its views.  Then we can delete the view
    // from from the adapter and finally set the adapter to the pager again.  Note
    // that we set the adapter to null before removing the view from "views" - that's
    // because while ViewPager deletes all its views, it will call destroyItem which
    // will in turn cause a null pointer ref.
    pager.setAdapter (null);
    views.remove (position);
    pager.setAdapter (this);

    return position;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns the "view" at "position".
  // The app should call this to retrieve a view; not used by ViewPager.
  public View getView (int position)
  {
    return views.get (position);
  }

  // Other relevant methods:

  // finishUpdate - called by the ViewPager - we don't care about what pages the
  // pager is displaying so we don't use this method.
}
```