# Can we add tabs in tab layout depending upon server response requirement?

Tags: android, android-tabs

I want to display the menu categories of restaurant in tabs. But the number of tabs will depend upon how many categories are there in a particular restaurant and the menu of that category will be displayed in `ListView` at the corresponding page. Is this possible in android? And please get me some idea how to achieve it.

Comment: are you asking if dynamic tabs are possible or not? and will you be changing the tabs once the tabs are already loaded?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager

Comment: Yes I am asking about dynamic tabs.

Comment: yes it's possible, you have to initialize the adapter once your data is fetched.

Comment: Yes I am asking about dynamic tabs. Actually what I want is that, I am fetching menus of different restaurants from server. All the categories will be displayed in tab layout and the dishes in that category will be displayed in corresponding page. So thats why I dont know what will be the number of tabs. Please help me out.

Comment: that's absolutely fine because once you receive the list of categories, initialize the adapter, that's it. The code for a sample adapter is given below, you have any doubt please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. After you fetch your data (probably as JSON) and save it to SQLite db you can load that data and create dynamic tabs. Lets say you will need only one fragment that represents the category fragment for particular category. You can generalize that fragment to support and load data depending on your category ID or other parameters that you pass.

You have lets say `HomeTabsFragment` that represents home fragment tabs. In that fragment when you fetch your categories you can define your `TabsAdapter` where you have `ArrayList<Category> categories` and assign that adapter to your viewPager `mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter)`. For every category you create one tab with title and fragment that fetch data only for that tab like in adapter :

```
  public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Category> categories;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context,ArrayList<Category> categories) {
        super(fm);
        this.categories=categories;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return CategoryFragment.newInstance(categories.get(position),position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categories.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return categories.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        if (observer != null) {
            super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

And CategoryFragment :

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

        public CategoryFragment(){
        // required empty constructor
    }
    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(Category category,int position){
        CategoryFragment fragment=new CategoryFragment();

        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("category", category);
        args.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public Object getCategory(){
        return getArguments().getParcelable("category");
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        //Fetch data for categoryID
        return view;
    }       
}
```