# Dynamically add and remove one instances of on fragment to view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to figure out how I can implement the following scene. I have an activity where the user needs to enter some information through edit texts, like names start times etc.. The user has the opportunity to add more than one information block. By hitting the add button as you can see in the drawing below. I thought about implementing it wit a `ViewPager` and a fragment. As I need only the same `fragments` multiple times I don't know how to dynamically add fragments to the Pager and how to remove them dynamically. If anybody knows a solution or an other approach that would be great. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: You will need - Android Swipe (Touch Gesture) Views Using ViewPager

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671777/2597775